# Ending a Sub inside Error handler

Tags: vba, excel

```
On Error GoTo Handler
Code
.
.
.
.
.
Exit Sub 

Handler:
Delete all the new created worksheets
End Sub
```

I want to delete all the additional sheets created by the program to be deleted if an error occurs and exit the program. The **End Sub** is inisde the **Handler** Is the above logic right? Also can someone advice a better way, if any ?. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is right. The `End Sub` should always be the last line in your sub procedure. Anytime you want to leave the sub procedure before your `End Sub`, you must use `Exit Sub` like you did.

Comment: Correct. No need to `Return` from `Handler:` before exiting.

Comment: Keep in mind that depending on the error type the other lines may not execute.

Comment: Consider this, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377152/error-handler-exit-sub-vs-end-sub